# I am not able to write bold text. Please help!

Tags: bold

I am a beginner in LaTeX and I have been using Textstudio as my main LaTeX editor for several weeks. My problem is that i am not able to write any bold characters.

`\textbf` will not work in this case.

I am sure there must be something in my code that is not allowing to write bold text.

Here you have my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}


\begin{document}

    \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[opacity=0.9,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{lol.jpg}};
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage

    \begin{titlepage}

        \textnormal{}\\\\\\\\
        \hrule
        {\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont \begin{center}
                APARTHEID   \end{center}}
        \hrule  
        \textnormal{}\\\\\\\\\\     

        \begin{center}
                 {\LARGE An article on Racism}
        \end{center}        


        \textnormal{}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ 

        \begin{center}
            {\Large Ramai Alejandria - 5I}
        \end{center}

        \thispagestyle{empty}

    \end{titlepage}

    \newpage

    \begin{titlepage}       

        \textnormal{}\\
        \begin{center}
            {\fontsize{35}{60}\selectfont \textbf{Table of Contents}}
        \end{center}


    \end{titlepage}     


\end{document}
```

Here you have a screenshot too

[image]

Please help me!

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What would you like to have bold?

Comment: Out of topic, but why would you need the package amsmath to write about apartheid?

Comment: Don't use `\usepackage{mathptmx}` together with xelatex.

Comment: what should i use instead?

Comment: I removed that line and it seems to work :) I would like to know why that package shouldn't be used

Comment: it is not for xelatex. If you want to use something times like, use `\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}` (load it behind amsmath!!).

Comment: also you should remove all those `\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ ` surely you get warnings from latex about those?

Comment: also what is the intention of `\texnormal{}` ? (it does nothing at all, it would set the content of the `{...}` in the document default font but with an empty argument it does nothing.

Comment: #David Carlisle I just wanted to create whitespace. Remember i am a beginner :)

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `\usepackage{mathptmx}` together with xelatex. The package is meant for pdflatex only. If you want a times like font use e.g.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
```